# How to build an literal array from list object?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have the list object that I'm passing using json. How can I convert it to array like you can see below using jquery or javascript?

```
List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItems>();
items.Add(new (){ItemName = "Apple", ItemCount = 5});
items.Add(new (){ItemName = "Tomato", ItemCount = 3});
items.Add(new (){ItemName = "Banana", ItemCount = 8});
items.Add(new (){ItemName = "Avokado", ItemCount = 5});
items.Add(new (){ItemName = "Potato", ItemCount = 9});
items.Add(new (){ItemName = "Onion", ItemCount = 1});
```

Array

```
var raw_data = [['Apple', 5],
                ['Tomato', 3],
                ['Banana', 8],
                ['Avokado', 5]];
```

Comment: You mean you have an array of objects in JS and you want to convert that to array of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.Net to do this.

Also you can use javascriptserializer see this 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: Use JSON and `eval()`. Just inform yourself a bit about javascript.

Comment: @Zebi, using `eval()` to parse JSON is really dangerous. You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to get the keys of an object and then use the keys returned in the for loop to associate the key with the value in the object:

```
var ob={x:1,y:2,z:3}
for(var prop in ob){
    alert(prop + ' = ' + ob[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work (using the compiler in my brain - not trustworthy)

```
String[][] arrayize(List<MyItem> items)
{
    List<String[]> answer = new List<String[]>;
    foreach (var item in items) 
    {
        answer.append(item.toArray()); // you need to write this api in MyItem
    }
    return answer.toArray();
}
```